# Unindexed remote repository found

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

I import the spring-framework source code to InteliJ IDEA 2016.3 ,just want to read some source code . But in the processing ,it shows

**"Unindexed remote maven repositories found" Disable...**

dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.1

repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot

repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot

repo.spring.io/milestone

I "update" the "repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" repository ,the index.gz is 200M+ . I wonder ,if i leave it be . Just disable the notification . Will it cause any prolems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repository index is used for dependencies code completion in the build files. Indexing is optional, you can disable this notification.